# Can I have per AppDomain Environment Variables in C#/.net?

Tags: appdomain

In a multi appdomain setup, is there a way to make SetEnvironementVariables and Get.... work within the appdomain only, so each appdomain can have different values for the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

No. :(

This example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Alternative");

            Proxy proxyObj = (Proxy)newDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Proxy).Assembly.GetName().FullName,
                                                                      typeof(Proxy).FullName);

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HELLO_MSG", "Hello World", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

            proxyObj.ShowEnvironmentVariable();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void ShowEnvironmentVariable()
        {
            var msg = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HELLO_MSG");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} (from '{1}' AppDomain)", msg, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
Hello World (from 'Alternative' AppDomain)
```

The process is the most specific level of encapsulation for environment variables, and `AppDomain`s will still "live inside" the same process.

Note that this will happen for all other process-level information (such as `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, command-line args, etc.

One possible solution would create worker processes (".exe" applications spawned from the main process), but that will certainly add some complexity to your application.